# Deriving Kepler's third law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity, dimensional-analysis

In Arnolds book in the section of dimensional analysis he tells to show that in a homogeneous central force field (i.e $U(ar) = a^v U(r)$ for some fixed $v$ and any $a$), if $r$ is an orbit, then for any $a$ so is $ar$.

This is easily done via showing that if $r(t)$ is a path, so is $s(t)=a\times r(a^{\frac{v-2}{2}}t)$ (with the same time normalization for the angle).

Then, he tells us to plug in $v=-1$ and deduce Kepler’s third law. We indeed see that if you multiply the orbit by $a$ (and the major axis in particular) then  Kepler's law pops up. This isn't a proof however, the interesting part of Kepler's third law is that it holds for all orbits with the same major axis, and we only show this on a 'one parameter' subset of the orbits.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question clearly. Are you looking for a generalization?

Comment: @holahola I am saying we didn't prove Kepler's third law. We merely proved that out of the (two dimensional world of orbits- think of choosing the pericenter, and the angular speed there, or energy and angular momentum if you prefer) if we look at all the multiples of some path, the period acts as we'd expect from Kepler's third law. For instance this current explanation doesn't care we took the major or minor axis.